# Why cant I get a variable from another class in another package

Tags: flutter, dart

My app folder structure is this:

```
├── /lib
│   ├── test.dart
├───├── /config
│   ├───├── config.dart
---
```

In test.dart I have a variable:

```
var _storage = FirebaseStorage.instance;
```

And in config.dart I wanna get this variable, so I tried this code:

```dart
import 'package:app/test.dart';

final STORAGE = _storage
```

But I cant get with it:

> Undefined name _storage

What can I do?

Comment: If variable starts with `_`, it will be private. That's why you can't access `_storage` inside config.dart. Try renaming it to `storage`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In dart variables like `_var` are private variables and you can only use it in the same class. You can do a `get` method to retrieve the variable outside the class like this:

```
//Inside the class in test.dart
void get storage => _storage;

//Inside config.dart
final storage = TestClass.storage; // Change the class name with yours!
```

If you want, check [here](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour)!

Answer (score 0):

This is because your variable contains a **_**. The underscore marks the variable to be only accessible inside the file. Removing the underscore will fix it.